# How to stop play 2.0.4 throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

When running the play console (2.0.4) it returns:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/matt/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/matt/src/app/project
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:       org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$.ideaSettings()Lscala/collection/Seq;
```

The exception is thrown at `PlayCommands.scala:214` and it looks like a [known bug](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/804-namespace-collisions-of-incompatible-typesafe-sbt-idea-fork).

The workaround however doesn't seem to be immediately apparent (short of upgrading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to temporarily disable your global [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin. You can do this by commenting out (`//`) this line:

`addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.3.0")`

Which should exist in one of these files:

`/home/matt/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt` or `/home/matt/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt`

Second, you have to remove (`rm -rf`) these directories:

- `/home/matt/.sbt/plugins/project`
- `/home/matt/.sbt/plugins/target`

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, I do a "play clean" & "play compile"

Comment: Sometimes, you cannot 'start' the play console.